# использовать только проверку jquery без php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-form

Если проверить вводимые юзером данных через [jQuery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) и просто записывать в базу данных результат то я смогу защитить себя от вредоносного кода? Ну что бы данные сразу фильтровались и не использовать валидацию посредством PНР

Comment: А что будет, если пользователь отключит JS в браузере? Или, что еще интереснее, подменит ваш JS на свой собственный (с другими правилами валидации)?

Comment: Хорошо с этим разобрался, можете посоветуете php валидатор?

Answer (score 1):

Используя проверку данных только на стороне клиента, сервер от вредных данных не защитить, т.к. такая защита легко обходится, ведь она полностью доступна для пользователя. Валидация форм на javascript, обычно, используется для помощи тому, кто вводит данные, как подсказки: поле заполнить надо обязательно, номер телефона правильный указать, в e-mail опечатку не допустить и т.д..
Но перед внесением данных в БД или какой-то еще обработкой на стороне сервера, полученные данные надо очистить от потенциальной угрозы хотя бы встроенными функциями php или другого языка.
В статье на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143035/) хорошо объясняется, и комментарии полезные.